# What are the rules for Dragonflights in the WoW TCG?

Tags: wow-tcg

As the title says.  I recently purchased a Twilight of the Dragons and War of the Elements booster box.  I got 24 packs of cards from each set and it stuck me that I didn't know the rules behind the Dragonflights or Elementals respectively.

Can anyone explain these rules or link to rules for them online?  A google search turned up nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the sets that you listed follow the same standard rules as the rest of the sets, however, seeing as UDE no longer supports the game, it makes it difficult to ask them questions. The most up-to-date rule set that I could find can be found here: http://www.cryptozoic.com/sites/default/files/uploads/files/wow_cr_v601_120409.pdf

Comment: I appreciate the link that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: You are most welcome. Enjoy.